# Python loop with next row values

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

Is there a way to make my loop work with no errors because there is no next value? Or not to use a foor loop for this at all?

Inside this function below I have another function with a for loop:

```
def funcA(self,perc,bloc):
    def funcA1(self):
        maxIndex = len(self)
        localiz = self.loc
        for x in range(0,maxIndex-1):
            if localiz[x,bloc] == localiz[x+1,bloc]:
                localiz[x,"CALC"] = True
            else:
                localiz[x,"CALC"]= False
        return self
```

I got it working by creating first the column **"CALC"** with **False** because the last line of my **df** will always be **False**. But surely there is a better way.

**EDIT**
I'm basically using pandas and numpy for this code.

The **bloc** that i'm using in the function is the **ID** column
The data structure I'm working with is like this:

```
ID   NUMBER
2    100
2    150
3    500
4    100
4    200
4    250
```

And the expected results are:

```
ID   NUMBER   CALC
2    100      True
2    150      False
3    500      False
4    100      True
4    200      True
4    250      False
```

Comment: Something is wrong with the indention: There isn't any block following `def funcA1(self):`.

Comment: what kind of data structure is `localiz`? (how can you access elements with `localiz[x,"CALC"]`?)

Comment: @CodingLambdas: this is only and excerpt of my function. funcA1 is nested in funcA

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: localiz is the way I'm calling **df.loc** for the DataFrame (df.loc[row_indexer,column_indexer])

Comment: @srWasabi Your code is still not valid. There has to be increased indention after a colon.

Comment: @CodingLambdas just edited it. In my code there is no indent problems, just pasted it wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I'm not familiar with this vector-style solution that numpy gives us, I think I couldn't make the most of the proposed solution that was given.

I did find a way to overcome the loop I was using though:

```
def funcA(self,perc,bloc):
    def new_funcA1(self):

        df = self[[bloc]]
        self['shift'] = df.shift(-1)
        self['CALC'] = self[bloc] == self['shift']
        self.drop('shift', axis=1, inplace=True)
        return self
```

With pandas.DataFrame.shift(-1) the last row will return NaN. This way I don't have to make any adjustments for the first or last row and I got rid of the loop!

Answer (score 1):

a pythonic way is this:

```
lst = [char for char in 'abcdef']
print(lst)
for i, (cur, nxt) in enumerate(zip(lst, lst[1:])):
    print(i, cur, nxt)
```

just note that `cur` will only run to the second-to-last element of `lst`.

this will print:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
0 a b
1 b c
2 c d
3 d e
4 e f
```

`i` is the index in `lst` of the `cur` element.

`lst[1:]` creates a new list excluding the first element. if your lists are very long you may consider replaicing that part with [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice); that way no additional copy is made.

---

this also works if your `arr` is an n-dimensional `numpy` array:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], np.int32)
print(arr)
for i, (cur, nxt) in enumerate(zip(arr, arr[1:])):
    print(i, cur, nxt)
```

with ouput:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
0 [1 2 3] [4 5 6]
1 [4 5 6] [7 8 9]
```

Comment: It doesn't quite answer the question, as @srWasabi isn't using a list, but probably a dictionary.

Comment: @CodingLambdas:  ow you mention it: the syntax `localiz[x,"CALC"]` looks more like a numpy array than anything else. oh, no, actually; `"CALC"` would not be accepted as index. what kind of data structure is that?!

Comment: My guess is a `dict` with `tuple` objects as keys, as `a[b, c]` is equivalent to `a[(b, c)]`. Or it is a data structure by a library or one @srWasabi has built himself.

Comment: I'm using pandas for this and '"CALC"' is the column of my dataframe I use to check the end of each group of rows